# Recover manually deleted call history

Tags: recovery-mode, data-recovery, calls, history

I was looking for an outdated third party call backup app which does not update instantaneously at the deletion of logs via the default phone app. Would that be necessary or is there any other way I can save the said deleted history?
If yes, could anybody suggest such apps? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there are no apps (as in an android app) to my knowledge but you can look at the binary data because what youve done is a soft delete and you need a hard delete to erase that information off the physical memory..

long to do and could be draining since you have to translate the binary also into higher level form .... you need a compiler for this. thats AFTER you find the location of the binary anomaly youre looking for (you can do this after too, thatll be easier, but youd have to decompile alot more code)

as long as your computer (in this case android) hasnt replaced that unused space (ie you havent downloaded too much information since) then its possible

im sure there are programmes to recover your code as i used to use these kinds of programmes since like 1997.

good luck finding that in 2019

but if you do btw... let me know.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely to be possible. Disk recovery software requires raw disk access which is only possible if your device is rooted.

Moreover, unlike regular desktop computers, your Android device is likely using SSD instead of hard-disk. Data recovery in SSD is a lot trickier than hard-disk due to wear balancing. However, the killer here is that your SSD device is likely TRIM-enabled, unlike with hard-disk where deletion simply marks the space as unused, TRIM will wipe the space moments after deleting the file.